# Enable blinking cursor in QML TextInput object

Tags: qt, qml, cursor, textinput

I have to work with a code with custom touch numpad/keyboard implementation. The input field is based on TextInput object and I can achieve the 'static' cursor by modifying its direct members

```
textInput.cursorVisiblity=true
textInput.cursorPosition=val
```

It works fine, but the cursor is not blinking.

After some research I find out the solution by calling the method:

```
inputVal.forceActiveFocus()
```

It gives me proper blinking cursor, but also provides default keyboard panel which overrides the custom one.

I'd like to somehow turn on only this blinking cursor or at least somehow block the additional keyboard panel

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there were defined some global virtual keyboard that I had to disable